# Do I need to install the PostgresSql in Project directory for it to work with psycopg2?

Tags: python, django, windows, postgresql

I am trying to make migrations to my newly created PostgresSql database when I run

> python manage.py makemigrations

it gives me the following error:

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "<MYNAME>" does not 
    exist
```

the  here is my windows username

I think it is maybe because I have installed PostgresSQl in the C: directory. I had to use

> psql --username=postgres

in CMD to get into the database and make new user with a superuser role.

Settings.py:

```
    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB_NAME'),
    'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB_ADMIN'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB_PASS'),
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432'

   }
 }
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably do `os.environ["POSTGRES_DB_NAME"]` etc., so you get an immediate error if the environment variable is not set (it looks like `.get("...")` is returning `None` and it's using your login username as a default -- not that I know anything about postgresql..)

Comment: I had to manually enter the username and then restart the pycharm IDE with admin permisisons to get it to work, now I am getting TypeError: Problem installing fixture

Comment: that sounds like another problem (for another question).

Comment: Thanks that worked

Comment: @thebjorn yes I am about to search/post